# Kerberos problem: GSSException: No valid credentials provided

Tags: spring-boot, kerberos

My application is sending data to Kafka, Kerberos is used for authentication. Everything works fine for around 20 days, then I get the following exception:

```
2020-01-07 22:22:08.481 DEBUG 24987 --- [fka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient                                                               : Initiating connection to node mkav2.dc.ex.com:9092 (id: 101 rack: null)
2020-01-07 22:22:08.481 DEBUG 24987 --- [fka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator                               : Set SASL client state to SEND_HANDSHAKE_REQUEST
2020-01-07 22:22:08.481 DEBUG 24987 --- [fka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator                               : Creating SaslClient: client=lpa/appX.dc.ex.com@DC.EX.COM;service=kafka;serviceHostname=mkav2.dc.ex.com;mechs=[GSSAPI]
2020-01-07 22:22:08.482 DEBUG 24987 --- [fka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector                                                             : Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node 101
2020-01-07 22:22:08.482 DEBUG 24987 --- [fka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator                               : Set SASL client state to RECEIVE_HANDSHAKE_RESPONSE
2020-01-07 22:22:08.482 DEBUG 24987 --- [fka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient                                                               : Completed connection to node 101. Fetching API versions.
2020-01-07 22:22:08.484 DEBUG 24987 --- [fka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator                               : Set SASL client state to INITIAL
2020-01-07 22:22:08.484 DEBUG 24987 --- [fka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector                                                             : Connection with mkav2.dc.ex.com/172.10.15.44 disconnected

javax.security.sasl.SaslException: An error: (java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]) occurred when evaluating SASL token received from the Kafka Broker. Kafka Client will go to AUTH_FAILED state.
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.createSaslToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:298)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.sendSaslToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:215)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:183)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:76)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:376)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:326)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:433)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:162)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator$2.run(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:280)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator$2.run(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:278)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.createSaslToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:278)
        ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:122)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:224)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192)
        ... 14 common frames omitted

2020-01-07 22:22:08.484 DEBUG 24987 --- [fka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient                                                               : Node 101 disconnected.
2020-01-07 22:22:08.484  WARN 24987 --- [fka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient                                                               : Connection to node 101 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials.
```

After restarting the application everything works fine for another 20 days or so and then I get the same exception again. These are the ticket properties in krb5.conf file:

```
ticket_lifetime = 86400
renew_lifetime = 604800
```

Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Comment: We are getting the same exception on Kafka connect for its kafka-hdfs-connect and the only meaningful workaround we found, is to lower traffic of these problematic connectors. We were trying to change ticket renewal mechanism inside HDFS connect but we just lowered frequency of this error.